# django-bootstrap-modal-forms additional data in trigger

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms, bootstrap-modal, django-bootstrap4

Using the following JQuery to trigger a modal:

```
        $("#view-large").modalForm({
            modalID: "#fullscreen",
            formURL: "{% url 'view-fullscreen' ID %}"
        });
```

The 'ID' i formURL is is what I'm missing. It's from a subset of a query set (double foreach) and it prints a data-id="" into a html tag. How do I get that ID into the Jquery